# Adding 48 hours to date/time field

Tags: excel, datetime, sharepoint

I have a date/time calculated field to which I'd like to take the created date/time and add 48 hours to it. I'd tried adding 2 days but it doesn't consider time so the results are inaccurate.

This is how I tried to do it:

=Created+"48:00"

If i do something like:
=Created+2 it will increase the day by 2 but it won't consider the time

if I do Created+"23:00" basically anything less than 24, it adds up currectly

Comment: You have to show us how you tried it so we can help you spot what's wrong with it.

Comment: Given the Sharepoint tag, how exactly are you trying to add 48 hours to the date field? Via a workflow? Timer job? Event Receiver? Javascript API? Changing data in an Excel file (hence the Excel tag)?

Comment: I updated OP. I'm using a Calculated field in SharePoint to take the Created field and add time to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since one of the tags is [excel], just append +2 to the created date/time cell reference:

ie if A1 contains 41522.5 (can be formatted as 5/9/13 12:00) then A1+2, with suitable formatting, can show 07-Sep-2013 12:00 PM.

Comment: Do you know if doing +2 will consider time values as well? So if my cell contains 5/9/13 07:34PM + 2 will it equal 5/11/13 07:34PM